# Infinite loop space as an endofunctor of compactly generated weak hausdorff topological spaces?

Tags: homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

I am trying to see whether it is possible to define smash product of infinite loop spaces using the space $S^{\infty}$.

Let C be the category of compactly generated weak Hausdorff topological spaces. For such a space X, define $\Omega^{\infty}X$ to be the space of based continuous maps out of $S^{\infty}$ into $X$. Being an infinite loop space equivalent to the existence of a space X such that X $\cong$ $\Omega^{\infty} X_0$

Suppose we define, for infinite loop spaces $X$ and $Y$, $X \otimes Y := \Omega^\infty (X_0 \wedge Y_0)$, for $X_0$ and $Y_0$ such that $\Omega^{\infty} X_0 \cong X$ and $\Omega^{\infty} Y_0 \cong Y$.

For instance, in the case for $QX \otimes QY$, this would be the same as $\Omega^{\infty} (Q(S^{\infty} \wedge X) \wedge Q(S^{\infty} \wedge Y))$.

Also, it would seem that $\Omega^{\infty}$ and $\Sigma^{\infty} := S^{\infty} \wedge -$ form an adjunction between spaces and infinite loop spaces.

My question is:

1. Is it true that QX is homotopic to  $(\Omega^{\infty} \circ \Sigma^{\infty})X$ for X a based CW complex?
2. If not, ss it true that $(\Omega^{\infty} \circ \Sigma^{\infty})X$ is an infinite loop space?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no question being asked here.  Also, what exactly is the space S^∞?  It would be best to give references for the source you are using.

Comment: Or at least define your notation. (Is S^∞ the increasing union of the n-spheres S^n ?)

Comment: @DanielAsimov yes, that's what I intended S^∞ to mean. There's not really a source I had.

Comment: Do you know that $S^\infty$ is contractible? So infinite loop spaces in your sense are always contractible.

Comment: $\Sigma^\infty$ is not usually defined as $S^\infty\wedge -$. Rather, $\Sigma^\infty$ is a functor from spaces to spectra, which sends $X$ to $\{S^n X\mid n=0,1, \ldots\}$. $\Sigma^\infty, \Omega^\infty$ define an adjunction of spaces with spectra, rather than with infinite loop spaces. You do have an adjunction between spaces and infinite loop spaces: ($\Omega^\infty \Sigma^\infty$, inclusion). But $\Omega^\infty \Sigma^\infty$ is not Map$(S^\infty, S^\infty \wedge -)$. Rather, it is (ho)colim$_n \Omega^n S^n -$. The distinction is very important.

Comment: @GregoryArone sounds like you can show that 1 is false.

Comment: @Cayley-Hamilton yes- I've made the distinction it just needs a proof.

Comment: @DanPetersen I know that S^∞ is contractible, but I don't know that ∧ works well with homotopy equivalence.

Comment: You did not define $QX$ in the question. Do you mean that $QX=\operatorname{colim}_{n\to \infty} \Omega^n S^n X$? Are you asking for a proof that this is not equivalent to Map$_*(S^\infty, S^\infty \wedge X)$? As Dan pointed out, the latter is always contractible (at least when $X$ is a CW complex, which one kind of assumes in such situations). So you just need to know that the former is not contractible for CW complex $X$. This follows, for example, from the Freudental Suspension Theorem.

Comment: Meanwhile, it seems like, for sequences of based spaces $X_n$ with $X_n \subset X_{n+1}$, $\text{colim}[X_{n},Y] \cong [\text{colim}X_n,Y]$ and $\text{colim} (X_n \wedge Y) \cong (\text{colim} X_n \wedge Y)$. I'm trying to figure out if these are true or false.

Comment: @GregoryArone ∞∧ is weakly contractible, but is it contractible?

Comment: @RonaldJ.Zallman This is not actually needed for the original question, but anyway the answer to your question is yes, assuming that X is a CW complex. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321983/homotopy-equivalence-of-smash-products. Or you can argue that if X is a CW complex then $S^\infty \wedge X$ has a CW structure, so weakly contractible implies contractible.

Comment: @GregoryArone doesn't this show that one or both of - ∧ X and [-, X] doesn't preserve colimits of diagrams featuring inclusions?